# Is there any way to delete a file from a fork and have it stay deleted every time you sync in github?

Tags: git, github

If I forked a repo and then modified it by deleting a couple of files, would there be any way to update the files I keep while making sure that the files I deleted remain deleted?

I think rerere is what I would use but I am not sure if that works. Is there any way to use gitignore?

Also would there be any way to do this even if the file names were changed?

Answer (score 0):

> If I forked a repo and then modified it by deleting a couple of files, would there be any way to update the files I keep while making sure that the files I deleted remain deleted? 
>   I think rerere is what I would use but I am not sure if that works. Is there any way to use gitignore?

It would cause conflicts. If you add the files in `.gitignore`, it may remain deleted after you resolve the conflicts. But if they update those files it won't remain deleted. You have to delete it manually.

> Also would there be any way to do this even if the file names were changed?

If the file names are changed, it will be added to your git files.